# Sum $\pmod{1000}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, elementary-number-theory, contest-math

> Let $$N= \sum_{k=1}^{1000}k(\lceil \log_{\sqrt{2}}k\rceil-\lfloor \log_{\sqrt{2}}k \rfloor).$$ Find $N \pmod{1000}$.

Let $\lceil x \rceil$ be represented by $(x)$ and $\lfloor x \rfloor$ be represented by $[x]$.

Consider $0 < x < 1$ then:

$$(x) - [x] = 1 - 0 = 1$$

Consider $x=0$ then:

$$(x) - [x] = 0$$

Consider $x=1$ then:

$$(x) - [x] = 1-1 = 0$$

So we must find $k$ such that:

$$\log_{\sqrt{2}}k \in \mathbb{Z}$$

$$\log_{\sqrt{2}}k = \frac{2\log k}{\log 2} = y \in \mathbb{Z}$$

$$\log k = \log(\sqrt{2}^y)\implies k = \sqrt{2}^y$$

So for a few integer $y$ values,

$$k = \sqrt{2}, 2^1, \sqrt{2}^3, 2^2,...,  2^3$$...

$k$ is an integer for powers of $2$.

$$\log_{\sqrt{2}} 2^x = x\log_{\sqrt{2}} 2 = x \frac{2\log_2 2}{\log_2 2} = 2x \in \mathbb{Z}$$

The sum is $1$ for $k=1$ but then $0$ for $k=2$.

$2^9 = 512 < 1000$ but $2^{10} = 1024 > 1000$.

but how can I compute the sum?

Comment: partial sum between $\sqrt{2}^n$ and $\sqrt{2}^{n+1}$

Comment: "The sum is $1$ for $k=1$ but then $0$ for $k=2$." is not true, since $\sqrt{2}^0 = 1$, the sum should be $0$ for $k=1$ and $k=2$." However, the sum is $1$ for $k=3$ (or any $k$ that is not an integral power of $2$).

Answer (score 4):

Note that $(\lceil \log_{\sqrt{2}}k\rceil-\lfloor \log_{\sqrt{2}}k \rfloor)=1$ unless $k$ is an integer power of $\sqrt 2$, which is when $k$ is a power of $2$.  In that case it is zero.   So your sum is $$N= \sum_{k=1}^{1000}k-\sum_{m=0}^92^m$$

Comment: (+1) Do you mean: 

$$k = \sqrt{2}^x$$ For any integer $x$? But why does subtracting the sum with $2^m$ give the answer?

Answer (score 2):

You've correctly identified two statements:

$\lceil x \rceil - \lfloor x \rfloor = \begin{cases} 0 & \text{ if } x \in \mathbb{Z} \\ 1 & \text{ if } x \notin \mathbb{Z} \end{cases}$

For integers $k$, $\log_{\sqrt{2}} k \in \mathbb{Z} \iff k = 2^r$ for some integer $r$.

Combining these, we get

$\lceil \log_{\sqrt{2}} k \rceil - \lfloor \log_{\sqrt{2}} k \rfloor = \begin{cases} 0 & \text{ if } k = 2^r, \text{ some }r \\ 1 & \text{ otherwise } \end{cases}$

So

$$\sum_{k=1}^{1000}k(\lceil \log_{\sqrt{2}}k\rceil-\lfloor \log_{\sqrt{2}}k \rfloor) = \sum_{1 \leq k \leq 1000\text{, } k \neq 2^r\text{ for any } r \in \mathbb{Z}} k$$

$$ = \sum_{k=1}^{1000} k - \sum_{r=0}^92^r$$

which I'm pretty certain you can work out.

Comment: (+1) How though?

Comment: How is what I said true, or how do you work out that sum?

Comment: How is what you said true?

Comment: @Lebes I've added a more detailed explanation.